# How can I stop the lines from repeating?

Tags: ruby

Look at this code. I got the desired result, which was to scan a person's input to see if it matches an internal array.

```
sentence = []
compare = []
database_array = ["Mouse", "killer", "Blood", "Vampires", "True Blood", "Immortal" ]

def parser_sentence compare
    database_array = ["Mouse", "killer", "Blood", "Vampires", "True Blood", "Immortal"]
    initial_index = 0
while compare.count > initial_index      
          compare.each do |item| 
         if item == database_array[initial_index]
            puts "You found the key word, it was #{item}"
          else
            puts "Sorry the key word was not inside your sentence"

          end
         end 
  initial_index = initial_index + 1
 end
end

puts "Please enter in your sentences of words and i will parse it for the key word."
sentence = gets.chomp
compare = sentence.split (" ")
```

Because each loop is telling it to repeat, it does so, but how can I stop this?

Comment: please add the input and output against the input.

Comment: Is there any reason why `database_array` is repeated here?

Comment: @tadman  That probably wrong copy paste I guess.. :)

Comment: initial_index is not a good name since you are changing it.  You also have loose ends.

Comment: A problem with splitting the sentence on spaces is you'll never find a phrase like "True Blood"

Answer (score 2):

In this case, regex will be more efficient and less error prone than splitting the input string, especially since you have a two-word phrase in the keyword list.

```
def parser_sentence(sentence)
  matching_words = sentence.scan(Regexp.union(database_array))
  if matching_words.empty?
    puts "Sorry the key word was not inside your sentence"
  else
    puts "You found the key word, it was #{matching_words.join(" ")}"
  end
end
```

Slight modifications can make it case sensitive (if you need it), or add word boundaries to the keywords so as to not match partial words.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that doesn't involve looping is to intersect your `compare` and `database_array` arrays, like so:

```
matching_words = compare & database_array
```

This will compare both arrays and create a new array containing only elements that are common to both. For example:

```
# If the user input the sentence "The Mouse is Immortal", then...
compare = ["The", "Mouse", "is", "Immortal"]
# matching_words will contain an array with elements ["Mouse", "Immortal"]
matching_words = compare & database_array
```

You can then check the length of the array and display out your messages. I believe this can replace your entire function like so:

```
def parser_sentence compare
    matching_words = compare & database_array
    if matching_works.length > 0
        puts "You found the key word, it was #{matching_words.join(" ")}"
    else
        puts "Sorry the key word was not inside your sentence"
    end
end
```

Note about the use of `join`, if you're unfamiliar with that, it basically creates a string using each element in the array separated by the separator string passed in, which in my example is merely a blank space; substitute for your own separate of course, or whatever you want to do with it.